# bind column values by group using hiveql

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

My dummy data:

```
| adv_id | dpa_id | json                                         |
| -------| -------|----------------------------------------------|
| 1      | 21     |{'adv_name':'Tesla', 'product_name':'Model X'}|
| 1      | 21     |{'adv_name':'Tesla', 'product_name':'Model Y'}|
| 2      | 22     |{'adv_name':'BMW', 'product_name':'X5'}       |
```

The problem is our hive system can only retrive 1 million rows of data at most. I need to bind the json together into a bigger one for every adv_id, dpa_id combo. Below is the output that I want:

| adv_id | dpa_id | json |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 21 | [{'adv_name':'Tesla', 'product_name':'Model X'}, {'adv_name':'Tesla', 'product_name':'Model Y'}] |
| 2 | 22 | [{'adv_name':'BMW', 'product_name':'X5'}] |

How should bind the values together? Thanks in advance.

Danny

Comment: json column type is a Map or String?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a group by and `collect_list`:

```sql
select adv_id, dpa_id, collect_list(json) as json
from table
group by adv_id, dpa_id;
```